# Why the simple command counter = counter + 1 do not working in Batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, gnu-make

i have made a GNU make file to generate a simple script in batch for a count function. The problem is that the counter is always 0. Do you know the solution ?

first try:

```
__EQUAL := =
$(shell @echo :loop >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set counter$(__EQUAL)0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set /a %counter%+$(__EQUAL)1 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @timeout /t 5 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @echo %counter% >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @if %counter% EQU 7 exit /b 0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @goto loop  $(__bracket_close) >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
```

second try:

```
$(shell @echo :loop >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set counter=0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set /a %counter%=%counter%+1 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @timeout /t 5 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @echo %counter% >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @if %counter% EQU 7 exit /b 0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @goto loop  $(__bracket_close) >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
```

third try:

```
$(shell @echo :loop >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set counter=0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set /a counter=%counter%+1 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @timeout /t 5 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @echo %counter% >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @if %counter% EQU 7 exit /b 0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @goto loop  $(__bracket_close) >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
```

Comment: can you please post the content of `checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd`?

Comment: ahem -- are you _sure_, you want that `set counter=0` _within_ the loop?

Comment: @Stephan i' m feeling so idiot, i will post all the solution!

Answer (score 0):

So, this is working! Thank you for the help:

```
$(shell @echo @set counter=0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)    
$(shell @echo :loop >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @set /a counter$(__EQUAL)%counter%+1 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @timeout /t 5 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @echo %counter% >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @if %counter% EQU 7 exit /b 0 >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
$(shell @echo @goto loop  $(__bracket_close) >> checkIfMergingIsEnded.cmd)
```